# Disable disclosure triangle next to files in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Much like other text editors with file browsers, Visual Studio has little disclosure triangles next to folders in the Solution Explorer. Unlike other apps however, it places triangles next to files as well and lets me see all methods inside those files.

I find that having disclosure triangles next to every folder AND FILE is horribly distracting and makes it hard to find what I'm looking for at a glance. Is there any way to turn them off? If not by default, then by using an extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **UseSolutionNavigatorGraphProvider=0** to registry to disable file expansion. The registry key path depends on the Visual Studio version. See http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/11/04/hide-class-info-in-visual-studio-20122013-solution-explorer/